# Change the heading User Accounts in user Registration Page

Tags: 7, users, theming

I am trying to change the heading in User Registration Page from User Account to Registration.

I tried pre-processing, but in the page variable title is empty and I can only see rendered html.

I also tried using the following code in the settings.php file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'USER ACCOUNT' => 'Registration',
  'Add new comment' => 'post new comment',
);
```

Comment: Check this thread : http://drupal.org/node/100450

Comment: May you show the code you used to set `$conf['locale_custom_strings_en']`? As far as I know, it should work.

Comment: @j2r Hi, sorry for late response. Actually I had used arg(0) and arg(1) conditions and changed the headings but I was not sure if that would be standard method. After seeing the given link I feel the method used is acceptable.

Comment: @kiamlaluno the code is $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'USER ACCOUNT' => 'Something',
  'Add new comment' => 'post new comment',
);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"User account" is the title that an anonymous user see for the "Create new account," "Log in," and "Request new password" pages. Replacing "User account" with "Registration" using `$conf['locale_custom_strings_en']` would cause the string to be replaced in every place where "User account" is used, which is not correct.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The solution is to replace the title callback used for user with another title callback. Create a custom module, or add the following code to the custom module you are already using.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['user'])) {
    $items['user']['title callback'] = 'mymodule_user_title';
  }
}

function mymodule_user_title() {
  if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    switch (current_path()) {
      case 'user':
      case 'user/login':
        return t('Log in');
      case 'user/register':
        return t('Create new account');
      case 'user/password':
        return t('Request new password');
      default:
        return t('User account');
    }
  }
  else {
    return t('My account');
  }
}
```

The code I used for `mymodule_user_title()` is exactly the same code used by Drupal 8 in its [user_menu_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu_title/8).

Other solutions, such as using the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module don't work too, as they replace the string independently from the context, which is important in this case. Users who are in the page for requesting a new password should not read "Register" as title because they are not registering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but when logged in, it is printing "username" while according the code it should "My account".

Comment: When you are logged in, and you visit http://example.com/user, you are redirected to `http://example.com/user/<user id>`. The title callback for that page is `user_page_title()`, and it has not been modified from my code.